# mysql_real_escape_string stopped working when I moved my code to another server

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

The following code works perfectly fine in my local xampp installation (Windows 7), but when I ported it over to a Win2K8 R2 server, the mysql_real_escape_string piece does not work. When I comment it out, it works fine. I am pretty sure this has something to do with the php.ini file but cannot pinpoint what it is. Perhaps my code should have been written differently to begin with.

```
function add_asset($asset_type_ID, $org_ID, $asset_desc, $asset_cost, $asset_value, $purchase_date) {
    global $db;
    $asset_desc = mysql_real_escape_string($asset_desc);
    $query = "INSERT INTO assets
                 (asset_ID, asset_type_ID, org_ID, asset_desc, asset_cost, asset_value, purchase_date)
              VALUES
                 (DEFAULT, '$asset_type_ID', '$org_ID', '$asset_desc', '$asset_cost', '$asset_value', '$purchase_date')";
    $add_asset = $db->exec($query);
    $last_asset_ID = $db->lastInsertId();
    return $last_asset_ID;
```

Specifically, when the record gets entered into mysql, the `asset_desc` field is blank.

Thank you!

UPDATE: After looking through the PHP error log, I found the following:

> [[function.mysql-real-escape-string](http://php.net/function.mysql-real-escape-string)]: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: First, it seems like you have a mix of DB calls. However, the mysql extension is likely not installed on your new server.

Comment: check the value of `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` on your server

Comment: @Paul - so if i use this code on a Linux box, regardless of my code, it will just work?

Comment: Probably :). Look, PHP was not designed to be used on Windows. Yes, it will work, but you'll probably end up having more issues than not.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary - would I find get_magic_quotes_gpc() in the php.ini file? what should the value be? thanks

Comment: if magic quotes is turned on (which is a bad idea), your data could be getting double escaped causing problems with your query.

Comment: Check your error log.  There seem to be cases where `mysql_real_escape_string` will generate an `E_WARNING` when something is wrong.

Comment: @Phoenix - I just posted an error in my php log seconds after you posted this. Look at my update above. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like whatever credentials you are using to connect to the database on your dev system are failing on your server.

`mysql_real_escape_string()` requires an active MySQL connection in order for it to work correctly; if you aren't connected to the database, it will fail.

- Check wherever in your code you are calling `mysql_connect()`; from the error message, it seems like your dev system is relying on the [runtime default values for the Mysql extension](http://php.net/mysql.configuration).
- Alternatively, the connection resource might not be accessible to `mysql_real_escape_string()` on the server's system.  From [the documentation for `mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) (emphasis mine):

  > #### link_identifier
  >
  > The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by `mysql_connect()` is assumed. **If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if `mysql_connect()` was called with no arguments.** If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is generated.

  Perhaps it's possible that your dev server is configured such that calling `mysql_connect()` with no arguments does establish a connection to the MySQL database server.  The most likely reasons for this are either dev MySQL server allows anonymous connections, or php.ini specifies valid default credentials.

  However, this fails on production, most likely because the production MySQL server does not allow anonymous connections, and no default credentials are specified in php.ini.

  Check over your code for situations where it is possible to arrive at the call to `mysql_real_escape_string()` without `mysql_connect()` getting called first (note that establishing a connection with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo.construct) doesn't count in this case).
- Since you're using PDO, consider switching to [prepared statements](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), which will eliminate the need for `mysql_real_escape_string()` entirely.

Comment: but the weird thing is, it is making a connection. the whole site is data-driven. and, everything in that function gets entered into the database with the exception of the 'asset_desc' field. I am using xampp on my dev machine and not on my server. i'm guessing this has something to do with it. perhaps xampp installed some extensions that i am not aware of??

Comment: also, I am not using mysql_connect(). I am using PDO. Again, the weird thing.. my code has not changed. this was all working fine on my dev machine

Comment: Oh.  You're using PDO?  Well then, just switch it over to using [prepared statements](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), and you won't have to deal with this anymore.

Comment: Thank you. I added a mysql_connect() statment before the mysql_real_escape_string and that solved my issue. However, I do not understand why it was working on my dev box and not the server. At this point, I don't care. I will move forward and fix my code. Thanks for your help

Comment: I will also re-code everything to use prepared statements and get rid of the mysql_real_escape_string altogether

Comment: I agree; that is curious that it works on one system and not the other.  I didn't see anything on http://bugs.php.net about this, and there doesn't seem to be anything in the PHP 5 changelog that would suggest something changed between versions.

Comment: Did some thinking, and I came up with a hypothesis.  I edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably thinking of "magic quotes"

http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Answer (score 0):

This function has been deprecated in php 5.3
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php

You will have to rewrite your code, ideally use PDO from now on and use prepared statements.

Comment: Thank you. I am on PHP 5.3.8 on both servers. One is working, the other is not. I will re-write this to get off of deprecated code, but for the time being, I need a quick fix.

Comment: Code in OP uses `mysql_real_escape_string()`, which I don't believe has been deprecated.  Did I overlook something?

Comment: There is no real quick fix for this. We had the same problem in our project, which was written years ago. We upgraded to 5.3.4 and just had to rewrite alot of code. Simply ignoring the mysql_real_escape_string will also work but will open up a huge security hole, don't do it!

Comment: @Phoenix read the documentation in the link I posted. I clearly says it is deprecated.

Comment: No it's not. there is a difference between mysql_real_escape_string() and mysql_escape_string()

Comment: Ok, so mysql_real_escape_string is NOT deprecated, from what I can tell. I am still not sure why this is working on one and not the other when they have the same PHP versions (5.3.8). I'm guessing there is something in the PHP.ini file which is not in sync. While Windows may not be the ideal OS for PHP, I don't think this is a Windows problem. PS - @Paul - this will be ported to Linux before it goes prod.

Comment: I don't think Windows has anyting to do with this. Many php sites are hosted on Windows. Even more are developed on Windows, then moved to Linux server, so just using php on Windows is not a problem with the exception of few extensions that don't work on Windows or are hard to find for Windows

Comment: @progger I'd develop on a Linux box if I were you. You'll probably run into issues when migrating. If you develop it on a Windows OS, keep it on Windows. By the time you're done developing, you'll have worked out all the bugs

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Answer:**

Connect to database first

Then use the mysql_real_escape_string.

Not the other way around......